# Apache IS_SUBREQ variable

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Does anyone knows when IS_SUBREQ variable is "true"? Everything, that i've tried, gave me only "false".

Info from apache docs

> IS_SUBREQ
>   Will contain the text "true" if the request currently being processed is a sub-request, "false" otherwise. Sub-requests may be generated by modules that need to resolve additional files or URIs in order to complete their tasks.

Could anyone show me some example when IS_SUBREQ is "true"?

Some of what i tried:
subreq.php - page with only

Testing browser's subrequest for image (I know that server doesn't care about it, but tried)

```
RewriteCond %{IS_SUBREQ} true
RewriteRule (.*)\.png$ null
```

Testing internal redirects

```
RewriteRule subreq\.php$ \tmp
RewriteCond %{IS_SUBREQ} true
RewriteRule tmp$ /index.html
```

No effect.

Comment: Provide link of your document?

Comment: I don't have real project know, I'm just trying to understand how does it work and I'll appreciate for any example

Comment: Ok you can at least show what rules you've tried to test it?

Comment: Alright let me test out these 2 rules.

Comment: May I know what you are trying to achieve? I can suggest you other ways to achieve that.

Comment: If you are hoping to “catch” a request that _has_ been rewritten already, and then goes through the whole rewriting process again (as is the case with rewriting when it is configured within .htaccess) – nope, that doesn’t seem to work; I tried that once and was not able to get it to “work” by any means – seems that `IS_SUBREQ` does not get set for this kind of scenario, only when a sub-request actually happens via some other module in the processing chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [`Apache Manual subrequest is:`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ns)

`a page which is included using an SSI (Server Side Include) is a subrequest, and you may want to avoid rewrites happening on those subrequests. Also, when mod_dir tries to find out information about possible directory default files (such as index.html files), this is an internal subrequest, and you often want to avoid rewrites on such subrequests`

So to get value of `%{IS_SUBREQ}=true` have a RewriteRule like this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{IS_SUBREQ} true
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ $0?s=%{IS_SUBREQ} [L]
```

- Then visit your website by opening this URL: `http://site.com/`
- Then inside `/index.php` if you dump `$_GET['s']` you will see value `true`.